# Return a promise with a model and a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, q

I have an error with a promise.

I try to use [angular-tree-dnd](http://thienhung1989.github.io/angular-tree-dnd) , but I have a problem with a promise.

**from my controller :**

```
project.getAll().then(function(results) {
    var projects = results;

    $scope.results = [];

    angular.forEach(projects, function(result) {
        $scope.results.push(project.build(result));
    });

    return $scope.results;
});

$scope.tree_data = $TreeDnDConvert.line2tree($scope.results, 'id', 'ParentId');
```

**my model :**

```
var Project = function(properties) {
    // Model
    this.description = null;
    this.file = null;
    this.name = null;
    this.ParentId = null;
    this.path = null;

    angular.extend(this, properties);
};

Project.prototype.setModel = function(obj) {
    angular.extend(this, obj);
};

Project.prototype.getAll = function() {
    return ProjectService.getAll();
};

Project.prototype.build = function(data) {
    var project = new Project(data);

    return project;
};
```

**my service (with $webSql) :**

```
this.getAll = function(params) {
    var projects = [];
    return db.selectAll('projects').then(function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            projects.push(results.rows.item(i));
        }
        return projects;
    });
};
```

I have no error but my home is empty.

I tried this :

```
project.getAll().then(function(results) {
    var projects = results;

    $scope.results = [];

    angular.forEach(projects, function(result) {
        $scope.results.push(project.build(result));
    });

    return $scope.results;
}).then(function(array) {
    $scope.tree_data = $TreeDnDConvert.line2tree(array, 'id', 'ParentId');
});
```

But I have this error :

```
angular.min.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property '__children__' of undefined
    at Object._$initConvert.line2tree (ng-tree-dnd.js:1456)
```

I think that my array is empty

Comment: Where is `project.build` defined? What does it return? I think that's at the crux of your issue.

Comment: In my model, I updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is the root of your problem:

```
"ParentId":"null"
```

Both of the items on your tree have a ParentId with the ***string value*** `"null"`. This probably means that the dnd library is looking for a node with an ID of `"null"`, finding nothing, and trying to access the `__children__` property on that `undefined` value.

The solution: fix the data in your DB so that the parent IDs are actually null values and not the value `"null"`.

Answer (score 0):

Good evening)
Please set a breakpoint, or use `debugger`, `alert`, `console.log` with `JSON.stringify(array)`, before your last operation:

```
$scope.tree_data = $TreeDnDConvert.line2tree(array, 'id', 'ParentId')
```

(last version with then and error).

I think you got correct array and trouble not in promises, but in line2tree syntax.

Comment: With this console.log(JSON.stringify(array)); I have this : [{"description":null,"file":"/release.txt","name":"CRM","ParentId":"null","path":"crm-site.net","id":6334,"created":"2016-04-25 19:01:32"},{"description":null,"file":"/release.txt","name":"CRM PREPROD","ParentId":"null","path":"crm-site.net","id":9856,"created":"2016-04-25 19:01:32"}]. But when I declare directly my array $array= [{"id": 1, "ParentId": null, etc..},{}] before $TreeDnDConvert.line2tree it works...

Comment: Maybe problem in null?
When you declare directly - null - is js value.
But on console.log array (returned from db) - it is string ("null").

Comment: Yes ! I updated "ParentId":"null" by "ParentId":null, it works !